# Celery: is there a way to write custom JSON Encoder/Decoder?

Tags: python, json, celery

I have some objects I want to send to celery tasks on my application. Those objects are obviously not json serializable using the default json library. Is there a way to make celery serialize/de-serialize those objects with custom JSON `Encoder`/`Decoder`?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

A bit late here, but you should be able to define a custom encoder and decoder by registering them in the kombu serializer registry, as in the docs: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#serializers.

For example, the following is a custom datetime serializer/deserializer (subclassing [python's builtin json module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#module-json)) for Django:

*myjson.py* (put it in the same folder of your settings.py file)

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime

class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):   
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime):
            return {
                '__type__': '__datetime__', 
                'epoch': int(mktime(obj.timetuple()))
            }
        else:
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

def my_decoder(obj):
    if '__type__' in obj:
        if obj['__type__'] == '__datetime__':
            return datetime.fromtimestamp(obj['epoch'])
    return obj

# Encoder function      
def my_dumps(obj):
    return json.dumps(obj, cls=MyEncoder)

# Decoder function
def my_loads(obj):
    return json.loads(obj, object_hook=my_decoder)
```

*settings.py*

```
# Register your new serializer methods into kombu
from kombu.serialization import register
from .myjson import my_dumps, my_loads

register('myjson', my_dumps, my_loads, 
    content_type='application/x-myjson',
    content_encoding='utf-8') 

# Tell celery to use your new serializer:
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['myjson']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'myjson'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'myjson'
```

Comment: Where should we put this code? Where do we import it?

Comment: @EduardLuca are you using Django? Please see my edit

Comment: Cool. I had to pull out the `register` call from `settings.py` (for some reason it threw a totally non-related error), but that worked. Thanks!

Comment: There is a typo: 'epoc' should be 'epoch' on lines 10 and 20

Comment: It will be nice to check `Promise` instances as well, i.e. gettext_lazy objects in `MyEncoder.default` method. `from django.utils.functional import Promise`

Comment: I ended up having to do:

```def my_loads(obj):
    return json.loads(six.text_type(obj), object_hook=my_decoder)```

otherwise, it complains about getting a buffer instead of a string.

Comment: How to add custom serializer for sending and receiving numpy arrays?

Comment: @TheGr8Adakron you can use the same pattern with methods available in another library. Exercise for the reader :)

Comment: Another note, in the Django case, another spot where most of this could live instead of a `settings.py` file is in the `celery_app.py` before `Celery` is initialized. (Of course, the `CELERY_*` settings will remain in the settings file, but the rest can move if that seems like tidier organization for your project.)

Comment: This used to work perfectly fine, but since celery 4.2 I cannot get it to work. Error when starting celery worker: Unrecoverable error: ContentDisallowed('Refusing to deserialize untrusted content of type json (application/json)',)

Comment: Kombu `utils.json.py` now provides, [`register_type`](https://github.com/celery/kombu/blob/35f24f1f01c7895926a990be0616a4582374749a/kombu/utils/json.py#L95). Pretty straightforward.
See [here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/projects/kombu/en/latest/userguide/serialization.html#:~:text=If%20you%20need%20support%20for%20custom%20types%2C%20you%20can%20write%20serialize/deserialize%20functions%20and%20register%20them%20as%20follows%3A) for usage.

Comment: @gabn88 I encountered the same, this is because Celery's heartbeat uses the default json type. So the solution is to still accept that: `CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json', 'myjson']`