# Celery task returning a list of pydantic BaseModel subclass: not json serializable

Tags: python, celery, pydantic

Consider this code:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyModel(BaseModel):
  x: int

appc = Celery(...)

@appc.task(bind=True)
def mytask(self):
    return [MyModel(x=0)]

res = mytask.delay().get()  # ERROR
```

Error is: `kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: TypeError('Object of type MyModel is not JSON serializable')`

I tried working with kombu serializers or with pydantic encoder but I really don't understand what is going wrong.

Comment: maybe return [MyModel(x=0).dict()] will work?

Comment: It does, but it requires to modify the task signature to return `List[Dict]` instead of `List[MyModel]` loosing all the benefits of pydantic...

Comment: Solved with custom serializer, as in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631878/celery-is-there-a-way-to-write-custom-json-encoder-decoder

Comment: I was about to say that. Perhaps it would be nice if you write a good answer to your question (since you already solved the problem), and accept it so other people may know the solution without going through the comments...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it in a easy way using pickle serialization:

```
appc = Celery(
    name=__name__,
    # ...
)


class CeleryConfig:
    task_serializer = "pickle"
    result_serializer = "pickle"
    event_serializer = "json"
    accept_content = ["application/json", "application/x-python-serialize"]
    result_accept_content = ["application/json", "application/x-python-serialize"]


appc.config_from_object(CeleryConfig)
```

In this way tasks and results are serialized with pickle and, as shown here (https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#pickledumpsmodel), Pydantic models are dumpable and loadable with pickle without issues.

In this way:

```
res = mytask.delay().get()
```

not only works, but `res` it is indeed a true `List[model]` so i.e. `res[0].x == 0` is valid and true.