# Object of type 'Request' is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to pass a few arguments form my view to my additional function, but I get error "Object of type 'Request' is not JSON serializable", I don't why is occured with me, cause I didn't pass request object to Response.

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def users_upload(request):
    if request.user.type != 't':
        logger.warning(f'Users upload ERROR: -{request.user.username}- not a teacher')
        return Response({'message': 'Not a teacher'}, status=403)

    try:
        user_file = request.FILES['data']
        file_format = user_file.name.split('.')[-1]

        if file_format not in ['csv', 'xls', 'xlsx']:
            logging.error('User upload ERROR: incorrect file format')
            return Response({'message': 'Incorrect file format'}, status=400)

        auto_file = AutoFile.objects.create(
            description='Temp file for user upload',
            file=user_file
        )

        upload_users_from_file.delay(request, auto_file.pk, file_format)

        return Response({'message': 'Task created'}, status=200)

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'User upload ERROR: unable to evaluate file format: {e}')
        return Response({'message': 'Error during file check'}, status=400)
```

What happened?

[image]
I can't show function "upload_users_from_file" because it distributes request object to large functions chain, anyway you can see by logger that ERROR occured actually in user_upload function.

Comment: What is `upload_users_from_file`? You pass `request` to this function. Also show the _complete_ error traceback.

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat, I edited my question, also can you tell my where I can see complete traceback if I running my app in docker containers?

Comment: "_anyway you can see by logger that ERROR occured actually in user_upload function._" that is not necessary you see the log there because you catch it in that function, as I say `upload_users_from_file.delay` is the most likely place where the error occurs. Also how would you see the error if you catch it? Also see [Python app does not print anything when running detached in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663459/python-app-does-not-print-anything-when-running-detached-in-docker)

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat, yes, you're right, when I replace delay() method I get correct behavior programm, but I want use delay in this place. Do you know any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

When `delay()` Celery must to serialize all the `delay` arguments to store in the task database. When Celery-worker gets this task, it deserializes arguments.

You try to pass the Request object as an argument to `delay`. Celery doesn't known how to serialize this type of objects.

Some advises:

1. Try to pass to tasks only objects that serializable by default - lists, dicts, strs, ints, etc.
   If you need to pass a lot of arguments, combine them into dicts or tuples.
2. You may want to make your object serializable. Please pay attention to these topics:

   - [How to make a class serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)
   - [How to register a custom JSON encoder to Celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631878/celery-is-there-a-way-to-write-custom-json-encoder-decoder)