# How to serialize a list of ndarray?

Tags: python, celery, numpy-ndarray, celery-task

I have a script which reads a video frame by frame and accumulate them in a deque.

```
labeled_frame_dequeue = [numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray]
```

I am trying to pass this list to a celery task

```
generate_clip_from_frames.delay(labeled_video_path, labeled_frame_dequeue, video_width, video_height, fps)
```

I have tried converting the deque to list and tuple but I am getting error `Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable` while passing it to celery.

Answer (score 1):

There are alternative serializers that are capable of serializing numpy arrays, for example `orjson`. You can find more info on custom serializers [here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#serializers) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631878/celery-is-there-a-way-to-write-custom-json-encoder-decoder). You could try and use an encoder like this one:

```
def encode(content):
    return orjson.dumps(
        content,
        option=orjson.OPT_SERIALIZE_NUMPY
    )

def decode(obj):
    return orjson.loads(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

- `ndarray` objects within your `labeled_frame_dequeue` list cannot be directly serialized to JSON, which is required for passing data to Celery tasks. `frame.tolist()` is also inefficient for large num of objects
- you can use the `pickle`, it allows you to serialize and deserialize Python objects, including ndarray objects.

```py
import pickle
import numpy as np

# Serialize the list of ndarray objects
serialized_data = pickle.dumps(labeled_frame_dequeue)

# Deserialize the serialized data
deserialized_data = pickle.loads(serialized_data)

# Pass the deserialized data to the Celery task
generate_clip_from_frames.delay(labeled_video_path, deserialized_data, video_width, video_height, fps)
```

This should be more efficient than using `.tolist()` for large numbers of objects.

Comment: I can't do this cause i tested this with 5 objects and ```frame.tolist()``` took 9sec. I would have 100s-1000s objects. so can't really do this.

Comment: yeah i get that, @raj-kapil, it would be inefficient, updated the code.